# For loop only running twice and generating subscript out of bounds error

Tags: excel, vba, finance

**Hello! I have a question regarding a program I created in VBA Excel.**
I have coded a program to extract financails out of YAHOOFINANCE and post them on a new worksheet in excel. However the program only runs **twice** before causing a subscript out of range error on this line

```
ReDim results(1 To rows.Length, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)
```

I am very unsure on why this is happening or as to why the program can run twice but no more. I have checked that my tickers are correct and than the stocks are available on yahoo finance.

```
Option Explicit


        Public Sub WriteOutFinancialInfo()
            Dim http As Object, s As String, x As String, y As String, z As String, w As String, i As Integer
        
            Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
          
            For i = 1 To 24
            
                y = CStr(Cells(1, i))
                
                
                
                
                
                x = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"
                z = "/financials?p="
                w = x & y & z
                
                With http
                    .Open "GET", w, False
                    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                    .send
                    s = .responseText
                End With
                
                Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, html2 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, re As Object, matches As Object
                
                Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument: Set html2 = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
                Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
                
                html.body.innerHTML = s
                
                Dim headers(), rows As Object
                
                headers = Array("Breakdown", "TTM")
                Set rows = html.querySelectorAll(".fi-row")
                
                With re
                    .Global = True
                    .MultiLine = True
                    .Pattern = "\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}"
                    Set matches = .Execute(s)
                End With
                
                Dim results(), match As Object, r As Long, c As Long, startHeaderCount As Long
                startHeaderCount = UBound(headers)
                ReDim Preserve headers(0 To matches.Count + startHeaderCount)
            
                c = 1
                For Each match In matches
                    headers(startHeaderCount + c) = match
                    c = c + 1
                Next
                
                Dim row As Object
                ReDim results(1 To rows.Length, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)
                
             
                For r = 0 To rows.Length - 1
                    html2.body.innerHTML = rows.Item(r).outerHTML
                    Set row = html2.querySelectorAll("[title],[data-test=fin-col]")
                    
                    For c = 0 To row.Length - 1
                        results(r + 1, c + 1) = row.Item(c).innerText
                    Next c
                Next
                
                Dim ws As Worksheet
                
                Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
                
                With ws
                    .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
                    .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
                End With
                Sheets("Sheet1").Select
                Cells.Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Range("J27").Select
            Next i
            
            
                
        End Sub
```

If anyone has any information on how to fix this or as to why this is occuring I would be very grateful. Thank you very much :)

Comment: What's the value of `matches.Count + startHeaderCount` when it fails?

Comment: `startHeaderCount` = 1

Comment: `matches.Count` = Nothing. Perhaps this is the source of the error.

Comment: Might be worth adding a test to see if you got any matches at all from the regex `Execute`